# Upgrading ruby installation using macports

Tags: ruby, macos, macports

Following

```
sudo port selfupdate
sudo port install ruby19
```

Where exactly is ruby installed on my mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default macports install stuff in `/opt/local`.

Most likely your ruby binary is installed as `/opt/local/bin/ruby19`

To get rid of `19` suffix install it as:

```
sudo port install ruby19+nosuffix
```

so this will install Ruby as `/opt/local/bin/ruby`

Comment: Or, after installation, create a soft-link using `sudo ln -s /opt/local/bin/ruby19 /opt/local/bin/ruby`. Then you could install another version of Ruby and toggle between them by changing that soft-link. That's the basis behind rbenv or RVM.